# What happens with doubles `articles.id` statements in a `WHERE` clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I am using MySQL and I would like to know what exactly happens (or what may happens) in the following cases when I run SLQ queries as-like

### Case 1

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE 'articles'.'author_id' = 2 
  AND (articles.id IN (46,4,5)) 
  AND (articles.id IN (4,5,16,40))
```

### Case 2

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE 'articles'.'author_id' = 2 
  AND (articles.id NOT IN (46,4,5)) 
  AND (articles.id IN (4,5,16,40))
```

*?*

In particular, I mean what happens with doubles `articles.id` statements in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is just a logical AND

```
1 && 1 = 1
0 && 1 = 0
1 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
```

Applied to the 1. case:

```
Value        IN (46,4,5)  AND  IN (4,5,16,40)    Result
4                 1                  1             1
5                 1                  1             1
46                1                  0             0
16                0                  1             0
40                0                  1             0
```

Applied to the 2. case:

```
Value     NOT IN (46,4,5)  AND  IN (4,5,16,40)   Result
4                 0                  1             0
5                 0                  1             0
46                0                  0             0
16                1                  1             1
40                1                  1             1
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, any given ID that appears both in the IN set and the NOT IN set will not be included.

When examining the row with ID 4 (for example) it would have to satisfy the boolean condition

4 IN (46,4,5) AND 4 NOT IN (46,4,5)

which is false, so the row with ID 4 would not be returned.

The same holds for any other row who's ID appears both in the IN clause and the NOT IN clause, because a given ID cannot be both present and not present in the same set of IDs.

Comment: In which case you're referring to?